# MVC Identity - split register into two views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

New to MVC.  I'm trying to duplicate the existing Identity Register.cshtml for two separate models (Student and Tutor) that have inherited the built-in Identity model ApplicationUser.  I did this so I'd have separate student and tutor models to use in the application, but store them both in the same place and take advantage of the same Identity User and Role functionality.

I modified the AccountController.cs, using the Register() action method as a basis to create RegisterStudent() and RegisterTutor() action methods.  The only difference is I replaced all the ApplicationUser references with references to the respective model.

I then manually copied the Register view and renamed it to RegisterStudent and RegisterTutor, changing the HtmlHelper BeginForm references.  When I navigate to those paths I receive a "The resource cannot be found." error indicating it doesn't like my path of `https://localhost:44301/Account/RegisterTutor`.

When I copy the contents of RegisterTutor.cshtml into the Register.cshtml file, it works like a champ.  Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1. You can create common view (partial view) that is called from inside both the `RegisterTutor.cshtml` and `RegisterStudent.cshtml`, which are called from actions `RegisterTutor` and `RegisterStudent` respectively.
2. You can directly reference the same view (the cshtml file) from both
   the actions as below:

   ```
   public ActionResult RegisterTutor()
   {
       var _model = 'Model Object'
       ....
       ....
       return ("~/Account/Register.cshtml", _model)
   }
   ```

Similarly

```
    public ActionResult RegisterStudent()
    {
        var _model = 'Model Object'
        ....
        ....
        return ("~/Account/Register.cshtml", _model)
    }
```

You can strong bind the `Register.cshtml` with the base model, if properties are same OR you can create an interface, which can be used to strongly bind the view and then both above models should implement it.